# How can I bundle jre8 with springboot application to run it on server which has previous java version installed?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have to run the springboot application on server along with another application which uses previous version of java. There is no java8 installed on server due to which I have to bundle jre8 with my springboot application so that it can run independently without using server's system variable.

Comment: Depends on how you plan to roll out your application. You can ZIP everything together, along with a start script. Put perhaps Docker might be a better option for your.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible could be a good option here. It was developed to enabled system administrators to be able to write scripts to deploy an application remotely, using existing unix/linux commands like scp.